# Logging a methods's name and parameters

Tags: java, logging

I've been working with a company that, in this current project, has to implement a policy of writing lots of trace logging in code (JAVA) that has already been completed for some time.

I am trying to avoid changing every single method just to write a logger.log('desired values') like code line on all of them. it's just too counter-productive.

Is there a generic way to log a method name, the parameters that it received, without changing much of the code? I've been researching annotations and stuff like that but there are a lot of methods with different parameters so i haven't been able to come up with a good solution.

EDIT 1:
The project is being developed on eclipse. I'm doing some changes in a portal using Liferay and JBoss.

EDIT 2:
I've followed a solution given to me here and used interceptors. The only change i had to do to the existing methods was to add an annotation to them, which was quite acceptable.
For more info search in this link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkeed.html

Comment: You should considere AOP, see [How to use AOP with AspectJ for logging?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839077/how-to-use-aop-with-aspectj-for-logging), [Traditional logging vs AOP logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555969), [Is using Spring AOP for logging a good idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071050) and [Spring: Standard Logging aspect (interceptor)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302090)

Comment: Yes, i do. i just edited the post to answear that more clearly for everyone. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interceptors http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkeed.html to intercept calls to public methods without any code changes, it is impossible to use this technique with non-public methods though.

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to use AOP and Java annotations. I would recommend to use [`@Loggable`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-loggable.html) annotation and an AspectJ aspect from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/) (I'm a developer):

```
@Loggable(Loggable.DEBUG)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

Comment: If you go with this approach do not forget to add jcabi build plugin to maven pom. Thank you for the suggestion. It really was something I was looking for. Great library.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Window->Preferences, select Java->Editor->Templates, create a new template named "logmeth" with Pattern i.e.:

```
if(logger.isDebug())logger.debug("${exception_variable_name} ${return_type} "+getClass().getName()+"${enclosing_method}(${enclosing_method_arguments})"+String.format("***",${enclosing_method_arguments}));
```

and press OK.

In java Editor write  logmeth and press <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and Eclipse will write i.e.:

```
if(logger.isDebug())logger.debug("e boolean hasFuture(man, woman)"
            + String.format("***", man, woman));
```

Eclipse is so cool.

Comment: Change the pattern to your needs.

Comment: `${enclosing_method_arguments}` will be empty for a method not accepting parameters though, so it will generate non-compiling code in that case.

Comment: @JoelWestberg Just change the Pattern to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [AOP](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/simple-introduction-to-aop.html). It enables you to inject code at runtime and thus add logging before/after each method.

Comment: I've already read a bit about this. but it didn't seem like it would help me log different methods like:

public String method1(String a, int b, boolean c)
public int method2(long d)


without changing the inner code of each individual method.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839077/how-to-use-aop-with-aspectj-for-logging