# Java - insert println() in each method of given class

Tags: java, regex, delegates

I have created a java class which delegates all calls to another class. 
I want that on each method call program will output some info - method name and arguments.
There are very many methods in that class, so I don't want to insert `System.out.println()` in each method manually.
Is there any way to do it with regex?

here is a sample method **with** required println() line:

```
private final PreparedStatement statement;

@Override
public void setNull(int parameterIndex, int sqlType) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("setNull: parameterIndex=" + ", sqlType" + sqlType);
    statement.setNull(parameterIndex, sqlType);
}
```

Comment: Regex? Do you know how to use regex? This sounds to me more like [loggin with AOP](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html).

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza I fell on the floor laughing when he said regex xD

Comment: what in the world has regex to do with this? but yes, you should look into AOP. voting to close as a duplicate, as there are plenty already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging a methods's name and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136790/logging-a-methodss-name-and-parameters)

Comment: Well, my idea was to copy paste whole java class to some text editor which supports regular expressions like TextPad and using search/replace dialog insert in each method line of code which would print method name and arguments..

Comment: @CardinalSystem nice to make you so happy.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this cases and similar we do not updated every function to add println, we usually use something that called **AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming)**.

> **AOP** is a useful technique that enables adding executable blocks to the source code without explicitly changing it. In our example, we don't want to log method execution inside the class. Instead, we want some other class to intercept every call to method power(), measure its execution time and send this information to slf4j.

please read this for more details [aop-aspectj-java-method-logging](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html) and 
[logging-with-aop-in-spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746676/logging-with-aop-in-spring)

**AOP** give you ability to intercept method execution and add your logic before,after or around the execution, so in your case you can add before execution interceptor and print the msg that you want.

**AOP** example :

```
@Aspect
public class MyLogger {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @before("execution(* *(..))") // after execution of any function 
    public void log(JoinPoint point) {
      System.out.println(point.getSignature().getName() + " called...");
    }
}
```

You can also use `point.getArgs()` to get all method arags