# how to trace api output request for a soap request?

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, soaphandler

I am working on implementing a REST api in java that is going to wrap a soap web service request,
what I have done is unmarshaled  the WSDL of the soap request using jax_WS way in eclipse
through the unmarsheling process I got classes of binding ans the stub of the web service and the types used by it
what I need is a way to see or log the output request "XML" of the soap request
noting that first I am call the rest API then the REST API calling the soap request,also sorry but I can not provide code...thanks in advance

Comment: you may find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136790/logging-a-methodss-name-and-parameters

Comment: @shikida dear I was about to use soap handler for the client side unfortunately I could not associate it with the write class then I realized that the way I import the WSDL through may affect the type and number of generated class when using Axis from using Axis2 and that left a little bit confused