# Where should logging occur in an MVC framework?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, logging

I've been doing, or at least trying, to do all of the logging within the controllers. But where should logging really occur, especially if the logging involves both server-side and client-side logging end points?

Note: this isn't homework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging in Java and in general: Best Practices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906233/logging-in-java-and-in-general-best-practices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging should occur where you are doing what you are trying to log. If you are running a query, add logging in your DAO class.

Have a look at [Logging in Java and in general: Best Practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906233/logging-in-java-and-in-general-best-practices) for some best practices.