# When exception occurs, logging specified message to console and logging its stack trace to log file

Tags: java, logging, exception

In my java code, when an exception occurs, I want to print my specified message to the console and write its stack trace to the log file at the same time. How can I do it? What I want to do is like following;

```
    try {
        //do something
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception occured."); //print console "Exception occured
        logger.error("Exception occured", e); //write entire stack trace to log file
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: It prints in two different files - an error file and regular file https://stackoverflow.com/a/48363934/1235935

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure 2 distinct appenders : one for the console output and another for the log file output.
 `slf4j` is an abstraction, not an implementation. So it doesn't provide specific appenders.

You could use logback or log4j2 as implementations. These provide appenders that you are looking for :

[LogBack appenders](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html).

[Log4J2 appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)

Comment: I see your point but after your answer I edited my question to avoid misunderstanding. Probably, you mean specifiying multiple appenders in configuration file xml but for the code level I didn't get your point. Could you look my edited question @davidxxx ?